# Check GetStreamAsync status

Tags: c#, stream, http-status-codes, getasync

Grabbing an image via `GetStreamAsync`, how do I determine status?

```
HttpClient OpenClient = new HttpClient();
Stream firstImageStream = OpenClient.GetStreamAsync("imageUrl.jpg").Result;
```

Sometimes this will give an error (403 or 404 typically) and I simply want to skip processing those results.

All I can find says to use the `StatusCode` property or `IsSuccessStatusCode`, but those seem to only work on `HttpResponseMessage`, which is from GetAsync, which does not give me the `Stream` I need to process the image.

Comment: There is a reason all of the HttpClient functions are async, if you don't plan on using actually async code you should be using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and using it's non async methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream doesn't have the response status code. You'll need to get the HttpResponseMessage first, check the status code, and then read in the stream.

```
HttpClient OpenClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await OpenClient.GetAsync("imageUrl.jpg");
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

Comment: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' could be found

Comment: You didn't await the task. Check my code above: var response = **await** OpenClient.GetAsync("imageUrl.jpg");

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpContent` are Disposable classes, why don't you use `using (...)` structure ?

Comment: And why do not use `IsSuccessStatusCode`?

Comment: For me solution is working! This inconsistency of API is something what Microsoft should change.

Comment: I'm going to add a comment to this old answer because I got burned by this recently: If you use something similar to the code in this answer, make sure you pass `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to `GetAsync`. Otherwise you'll end up reading the whole file into memory even if the status code is something else than 200. This article has more information: https://medium.com/@szntb/getting-burnt-with-httpclient-9c1712151039