# How to get the `HttpStatusCode` without reading the content from the server?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I retrieve a huge `JSON` data from the server
The problem is that, the serialization process have performance cost, in order to minimize this cost I need to retrieve this data as a stream first and then, with the help of Newtonsoft's `Json.net` library [serialize the data as a stream](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) to the required type.
Now I'm doing this:

```
using (var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUrl))
{
    using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        using(var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var items = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<TEntity[]>(jsonReader);
            //Some logic
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is good, but I need to get the `HttpStatusCode` from the response object, but I cannot get the response object while working with streams. I searched for a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724299/check-getstreamasync-status) question.
Now, my question is: Is there any difference between the two approaches?
Calling `GetAsync` to get the response object and then calling `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` will it have performance overhead?
 I mean how does `HttpClient` do it?
 Does it load the data into the memory and then when I call `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` I read the data from the memory as stream?
Or, when I call `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` I'm getting the data as stream directly from the server?

Comment: `Now, my question is: Is there any difference between the two approaches?` Did you try the two of them? Did they act the same?

Comment: No, I haven't. I was looking for a way to use `stream` for the performance and getting the `HttpStatusCode` at the same time. In the other question, the answer doesn't explain if they do the same work. I was wondering if someone have tried both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpcompletionoption) is your friend.

> The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. The content is not read yet.

You can use it in some overloads of HttpClient methods:

```
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, 
                                     HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        //...
```

`HttpCompletionOption` controls whether or not the response is handed back to the caller after it has completely downloaded (`ResponseContentRead`) or immediately after the headers are received (`ResponseHeadersRead`), which allows for streaming and conservation of memory resources.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will try it that way.